# Ideal Ball weight to get the maximum range from a ball launcher?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, energy

i am building a ball launcher, to launch a line of baits into the sea, the line has 25 baits, each bait weights 30 grams (about 1oz)

ideal shooting degree seems to be 45 to get maximum range, What i would like to figure out is the ideal weight of the ball to achieve the greatest distance for a shot.

Here is an illustration of what I want to do:[image]

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What question are you asking about physics? If you are asking for a calculation, what part of the calculation are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the mass of the ball is $M$ and the total mass of the baits and line is $m$.

If we ignore gravity then after the ball is launched with speed $V$ its initial momentum $MV$ is gradually shared with all the baits. The final momentum of the ball plus baits is $(M+m)v$ where $v$ is their final speed. The final momentum is the same as the initial momentum so $$MV=(M+m)v$$

To get the maximum range we should make $v$ as large as possible. We might assume that we are limited by the maximum amount of chemical energy or elastic potential energy $E$ which can be stored in the gun. This equals the kinetic energy with which the ball is launched so $$E=\frac12 MV^2$$

Combining the above two equations we get 
$$v=\frac{M}{M+m}\sqrt{\frac{2E}{M}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}+\frac{m}{\sqrt{M}}} \sqrt{2E}$$

The maximum value of $v$ occurs when the denominator is a minimum, that is when $\sqrt{M}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{M}}$ which requires $M=m$.

**The largest range is achieved when the mass of the ball equals the total weight of the baits and line.**

Comment: Note: There should be no M under the last square root in the final expression for v.